# Вытащить из базы данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Всем привет, есть база занных, в которых одно из полей является JSON данными в формате:

```
[tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 289237
                            [name] => vk
                            [element_type] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 315875
                            [name] => leadform
                            [element_type] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 343622
                            [name] => Ростов
                            [element_type] => 2
                        )

                )
```

Я пытаюсь вытащить все записи по определенному запросу mySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table
WHERE date_create>='2017-08-01'
AND JSON_EXTRACT(tags, "$**.name") = "vk"
```

т.е. все записи, где есть тег со значением `name` = `vk`
Но увы я недостаточно знаю язык запросов. Может кто поможет составить верный запрос

Comment: Удалось вытащить частично по запросу
`AND JSON_EXTRACT(tags, "$[0].name") = "vk"`
НО не факт что у нас значение будет именно в первой ячейке [0] порядок не четкий

Comment: а что если что то вроде - `SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE date_create>='2017-08-01' AND JSON_CONTAINS (tags, [{"name": "vk"}]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table
WHERE date_create>='2017-08-01'
AND JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'vk') IS NOT NULL
```

`JSON_SEARCH` находет путь к элементу или возвращает `NULL` если не находит. Доки: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

Другой вариант:

```
AND JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '{"name": "vk"}')
```

Comment: Вот кстати очень хорошее решение, мне помогло, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста :) `JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '{"name": "vk"}')` кстати тоже работает.